# Using more than one copy option for filesystem::copy in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

I am using `filesystem` to copy a directory. I want the directory to be copied recursively and to overwrite any existing files.

I use the following code to copy the directory and it works. However, I can only set `recursive` OR `overwrite_existing` for `copy_options`, not both.

```
filesystem::copy(pathInput, pathOutput, filesystem::copy_options::recursive);
```

Is there a way that I can use multiple options with the copy function?

I am using [this site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_options) as a reference for the options but it does not say anything about using more than one option at the same time.

Comment: OP: the page you link to has right on it *copy_options satisfies the requirements of BitmaskType (which means the bitwise operators operator&, operator|, operator^, operator~, operator&=, operator|=, and operator^= are defined for this type). none represents the empty bitmask; every other enumerator represents a distinct bitmask element.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're bit flags so

```
filesystem::copy(pathInput, pathOutput, filesystem::copy_options::recursive | filesystem::copy_options::overwrite_existing)
```

To add additional detail, on a lower level each flag is a bit (on/off) in an integer so...

01 = overwrite 10 = recursive 11 = both 00 = none

the | operator is a binary or which equals true if either bit (or both) is true so:

> 01 | 10 = 11
>
> 00 | 11 = 11
>
> 11 | 11 = 11
>
> 00 | 00 = 00

Comment: They are exactly bit flags. See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_options): "`copy_options` satisfies the requirements of `BitmaskType` (which means the bitwise operators `operator&`, `operator|`, `operator^`, `operator~`, `operator&=`, `operator|=`, and `operator^=` are defined for this type). "

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to use the bit operator `&`  instead of `|`. Updated my code and it works now.

Answer (score 2):

Using the reference site you gave it says right above the constant definitions that

*At most one copy option in each of the following options groups may be present, otherwise the behavior of the copy functions is undefined.*

So you can just do what everyone else says and or the two values together since they are from different options groups.